# I have started learning synchronization in threading.I wrote some code.Why sometimes synchronized block doesn't work right?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, java-threads

I am just trying to increment variable with 2 thread but sometimes shows value isn't right.

```
public class SynchBlock {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SynchBlock obj= new SynchBlock();
        obj.dowork();
}
    }
```

Method with Synchronized block

```
    private int count;
    public void call() {
        synchronized (this) {
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Method of SynchBlock runs threads

```
    public void dowork() throws InterruptedException {
        th1.start();
        th2.start();
        th1.join();
        th1.join();
        System.out.println(count);
    }
```

Thread class 1 just increases value of count

```
    Thread th1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                call();
            }
        }

    });
```

Thread class 2 just increases value of count

```
    Thread th2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                call();
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't join `th2`. You join `th1` twice, so sometimes you print `count` before `th2` is finished.